# Get all documents NAMES in a collection in Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Given the collection "events", is there a way to retrieve ONLY the documents names inside the "events" collection?

`await firebase.firestore().collection('events').get()` gives us the entire collection with all documents data, resulting in large memory consumption.; I'd like to retrieve only the names but I don't know if it is possibile.